# Flutter - Splash Screen Setting

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I want to set Splash Screen with an image.
It doesn't work properly.

Let me show you my settings.

[image]

So I changed the part as

```
android:src="@mipmap/launch_image"
```

But when I open app splash screen image is not `launch_image`.
But the splash image is `ic_launcher.png` image
I want to set `ic_laucher.png` as icon image
and I want to set `launch_image.png` as splash screen image.

Can you let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a package on pub.dev that sets up the splash screen for you automatically: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash.  I think you will find it a lot easier than setting up the splash screen manually.

Comment: I am having difficulty with your package, I've set everything 100%, however the splashscreen doesn't show. Instead it shows a black background with the icon of the project. Any ideas?

Comment: For me it was paying attention to the Android 12 settings, setting that and then re-running create.